# When are these two definitions of a continuous action equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, topological-groups

Apologies in advance that this is a somewhat vague question. I attempt to make precise below what would constitute an answer for me.

Let $G$ be a topological group and $X$ a topological space on which $G$ acts as a set. I have in my mind two different definitions of the statement "$G$ acts continuously on $X$," and I would like to know when they are equivalent. The **real** definition, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_group_action), is the assertion that the action map

$$\alpha: G\times X \rightarrow X$$

given by

$$(g,x)\mapsto gx$$

is a continuous map. This definition is very concise and conceptually slim. But the following **alternative** definition feels natural to me too, probably because it consists of the information I actually want to know about the action:

- For any $g\in G$, the map $\rho_g:X\rightarrow X$ given by $x\mapsto gx$ is a homeomorphism, thus there is a natural group homomorphism $\rho: G\rightarrow \operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ given by $g\mapsto \rho_g$, where $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ is the group of homeomorphisms of $X$.
- Endow $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ with the compact-open topology. Then $\rho:G\rightarrow \operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ is a continuous map of topological spaces.

I assume that these definitions are not equivalent at the generality of my setup, since if $X$ is a totally general topological space, I know that weird things can happen. For example, my impression is that $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ needn't be a topological group. (While I am unaware of a specific example, there is a theorem due to Richard Arens [Theorem 4 [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371787?seq=1)] stating that *if* $X$ is locally compact, locally connected hausdorff, then $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ with the compact-open topology is a topological group; so presumably this fails in greater generality. Of course, it is possible in principle that the definitions are equivalent even when $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ is not a topological group.)

On the other hand, the real definition does *imply* the alternative definition in full generality (see appendix below), and it seems likely to me that under some "ordinary circumstances" they will coincide. My question is:

**Under what topological conditions on $G$ and $X$ do the two above definitions of a continuous group action coincide with each other?**

This question is admittedly vague. I would be happy with any set of conditions sufficient for equivalence that are in the language of general (i.e., point-set) topology. For example, "this is true if $G$ and $X$ are locally connected, locally compact hausdorff [or whatever]" would be a satisfying answer, whereas, "this is true if $G$ is a Lie group and $X$ is a manifold" is narrower than what I am looking for.

**Appendix: proof that the standard definition implies the alternative one:**

Suppose that the action map $\alpha:G\times X\rightarrow X$ is continuous. A "cross-section embedding" $X\hookrightarrow G\times X$ given, for a fixed $g$, by $x\mapsto (g,x)$, is a continuous map. (An open set in $G\times X$ is a union of sets $V\times U$, with $V\subset G$ and $U\subset X$ open, and the pullback in $X$ under this "cross-section embedding" will be the union of just those $U$'s whose corresponding $V$ contains $g$. This is a union of open sets, therefore open.) Therefore, fixing $g$, the composite map

$$ X\hookrightarrow G\times X \xrightarrow{\alpha} X $$

given by

$$ x\mapsto (g,x) \mapsto gx$$

is continuous. This is the map $\rho_g$. It is inverse to $\rho_{g^{-1}}$, which is continuous for the same reason. Thus $\rho_g$ is a homeomorphism for every $g$, in full generality.

Let $K,U\subset X$ be compact and open, respectively, and let $[K,U]\subset \operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ be the set of homeomorphisms $f:X\rightarrow X$ satisfying $f(K)\subset U$. Then $\rho^{-1}([K,U])$ consists of those $g\in G$ such that $\rho_g(K)\subset U$. I would like to know that $\rho^{-1}([K,U])$ is open, since the $[K,U]$'s form a subbase for the topology of $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$.

Fix an arbitrary $g\in \rho^{-1}([K,U])$. Let $k\in K$ be arbitrary. Then $gk = \rho_g(k)=\alpha(g,k)\in U$, i.e., $(g,k)\in\alpha^{-1}(U)$. Since $\alpha$ is continuous and $U$ is open, $\alpha^{-1}(U)\subset G\times X$ is open, thus $(g,k)$ is contained in a basis open set of the product topology on $G\times X$ that is entirely contained in $\alpha^{-1}(U)$. Let it be $V_{gk}\times U_{gk}$, where $V_{gk}\subset G$ and $U_{gk}\subset X$ are open, and $g\in V_{gk}$ while $k\in U_{gk}$. Keeping $g$ fixed while allowing $k$ to vary across $K$, we get an open cover $\{U_{gk}\}|_{k\in K}$ of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, this cover has a finite subcover $U_{gk_1},\dots,U_{gk_s}$. Let $V=\bigcap_1^s V_{gk_j}$. Because this intersection is finite, $V$ is an open subset of $G$. Since $V\times U_{gk_j} \subset V_{gk_j}\times U_{gk_j}\subset \alpha^{-1}(U)$ for each $j=1,\dots,s$, we have

$$ V\times K \subset V\times \bigcup_1^s U_{gk_j} = \bigcup_1^s V\times U_{gk_j} \subset \alpha^{-1}(U).$$

The first containment is because by construction, $U_{gk_1},\dots,U_{gk_s}$ is a cover of $K$. Translating the containment $V\times K\subset \alpha^{-1}(U)$ in terms of $\rho$, this says that $V\subset\rho^{-1}([K,U])$. Now clearly $g\in V$ since $g\in V_{gk_j}$ for each $j$ (in fact, $g\in V_{gk}$ for each $k$). Thus we have identified an open set of $G$ containing $g$ and contained in $\rho^{-1}([K,U])$. Since $g$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\rho^{-1}([K,U])$ is open. Therefore, $\rho$ is continuous.

This proof that $\rho$ is continuous is a direct adaptation of [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1089768/13120) given by Olivier Begassat in the special case that $X=G$ and the action is regular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If $X$ is locally compact hausdorff, then the two definitions are equivalent.**

Local connectedness appears not to be needed for this, nor do we appear to need any topological constraint on $G$ beyond the setup.

We follow the notational conventions set up in the OP.

**Theorem:** Assume $X$ is locally compact hausdorff. Then the following are equivalent:

- The action map $\alpha:G\times X\rightarrow X$ is continuous.
- Each element action $\rho_g:X\rightarrow X$ (defined by $\rho_g(x)=\alpha(g,x)$) is continuous, and the induced representation map $\rho:G\rightarrow \operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ (defined by $g\mapsto \rho_g$) is continuous.

**Proof:** It was already proven in the OP (without needing either the local compactness or the hausdorffness assumptions) that if $\alpha$ is continuous, then $\rho$ is continuous (and its image lands in $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$). So, we suppose each $\rho_g$ is continuous, and $\rho$ is continuous, and $X$ is locally compact hausdorff, and aim to establish $\alpha$ is continuous.

Let $U\subset X$ be open, and consider $\alpha^{-1}(U)\subset G\times X$. We have to show it is open. Take an arbitrary $(g,x)\in \alpha^{-1}(U)$; it will suffice to find an open set of $G\times X$ containing $(g,x)$ and contained in $\alpha^{-1}(U)$.

Since by assumption $\rho_g$ is continuous, the set $\rho_g^{-1}(U)\subset X$ is open. Note that it contains $x$, because $(g,x)\in\alpha^{-1}(U)$, or equivalently, $\rho_g(x)\in U$.

Since $X$ is locally compact hausdorff, $x$ has a local base of compact neighborhoods. In particular, there is a compact set $K$ contained in the open set $\rho_g^{-1}(U)$ and containing an open set $U_x$ that in turn contains $x$:

$$x\in U_x\subset K\subset \rho_g^{-1}(U) \subset X.$$

The set $[K,U]\subset \operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ is open, by definition of the topology on $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$. By supposition, $\rho$ is continuous; therefore $\rho^{-1}([K,U])\subset G$ is open; call it $V$.

Since $K\subset \rho_g^{-1}(U)$, i.e., $\rho_g(K)\subset U$, we have that $g\in \rho^{-1}([K,U])$; in other words, $g\in V$. Thus $(g,x)$ is contained in $V\times U_x$. Meanwhile, by definition of $V$, for any $h\in V$ we have $\rho_h(K)\subset U$, and in particular, $\rho_h(U_x)\subset U$ since $U_x\subset K$. It follows that the entirety of $V$ sends $U_x$ into $U$; in other words, $V\times U_x\subset \alpha^{-1}(U)$.

Now $V\times U_x\subset G\times X$ is open by definition of the product topology, since $V\subset G$ and $U_x\subset X$ are open. Thus we have identified an open set $V\times U_x$ containing $(g,x)$ and contained in $\alpha^{-1}(U)$. We conclude $\alpha$ is continuous.